# Version restrictions of Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried using Bootstrap 3.3.7 with JQuery 3.1.0, but after this step my DropDown Menu did not work anymore. Searched already on the website of bootstrap.
Is there any restrictions or requirement by Bootstrap, because with it works fine with jquery 1.10.2.

Comment: It should work on jq 3.x. Any error in console? BTW, be more explicit about `did not work anymore`?! Have you tested it on different browsers? Etc...

Comment: Yes, tested it in different browsers. The dropdown does not open if I click on it.